# Need to downgrade opencl files, desktop keeps crashing

Tags: grub2, startup, opencl

I updated open cl software, which in turn, after a crash, rebooted my computer to get a black desktop:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_kkB1L8ivCLOEUwRnFDQko2WUU

With this I am unable to access drop down menus anywhere on anything: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_kkB1L8ivCLUW5qWDZ4VF9tVG8

I was able to temporarily resolve the issue by booting into safe mode through the grub menu. Sadly, after an update to the OS I can no longer access the grub menu to boot in to safe mode.

How do I downgrade opencl properties back to what they once were so I can get all my menus back?

Comment: You can get to the grub menu by pressing Shift or Esc as the system boots.  Ubuntu doesn't seem to include OpenCL out of the box.  How did you install OpenCL?  Exactly what commands did you use to update OpenCL?

Comment: There was a page here on ask ubuntu which i followed a link that was provided and brought me to the directions to download from terminal. my system recognized it already(I take it was downloaded with something else i installed.). So I followed the procedure which led me to upgrading the software. After putting in the command line, all seemed well. But now I experience the above. And as stated above I know how to get to the grub menu but after a recent update i now no longer have access.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you'll need to provide specifics.

Comment: The sad thing is i am unable to provide specifics because I am unable to access the browser history to see where i would have gone to get the info because i cannot access/see drop down menus on any browser or folder, and right clicking feature only works in case scenario's, because i can't access any of the startup menus is there a way to reinstall ubuntu fresh without restarting? (restart feature doesn't work either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved i dont remember how exactly but this problem is no more.

Comment: How does this answer the question? The [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) provides information about what should/shouldn't be posted as answer.